# Issue with overloading insertion and extraction operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

currently learning C++. I've encountered an issue where I've overloaded the operators and have included a default constructor, however, VSC keeps saying I haven't included one. I've compared my code with a similar one that I've found and has very similar syntax, yet I still can't run it. Was wondering if I may have had an oversight, etc.

```
class DegreeAngle
{
    private:
        int angle;
    public:
        DegreeAngle(){angle = 0;}
        DegreeAngle(const int angleInput) : angle(angleInput){}
        friend int operator+(const DegreeAngle& angleOne, const DegreeAngle& angleTwo);
        friend int operator-(const DegreeAngle& angleOne, const DegreeAngle& angleTwo);
        friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, const DegreeAngle& angle);
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const DegreeAngle& angle);
};
int main()
{
    DegreeAngle a1;
    std::cin >> a1;
    std::cout << a1;
}
int operator+(const DegreeAngle& angleOne, const DegreeAngle& angleTwo)
{
    DegreeAngle sumAngle = angleOne.angle + angleTwo.angle;
    return sumAngle.angle;
}
int operator-(const DegreeAngle& angleOne, const DegreeAngle& angleTwo)
{
    DegreeAngle subAngle = angleOne.angle - angleTwo.angle;
    assert(subAngle.angle>=0);
    return subAngle.angle;
}
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, const DegreeAngle& angleInput) 
{
    ins >> angleInput.angle;
    return ins;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const DegreeAngle& angleInput) 
{
    outs << angleInput.angle;
    return outs;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the _exact_ error message.  One issue I can see is that your `operator>>` function is trying to modify a `const DegreeAngle&` object.  This is not allowed.  That parameter should be non-const.

Answer (score 0):

Your program currently compile and have infinite recursion:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, const DegreeAngle& angleInput) 
{
    ins >> angleInput.angle; // No operator >>(istream&, const int&)
                             // but DegreeAngle(int) is not explicit
                             // so we use ins >> DegreeAngle(angleInput.angle)
                             // -> infinite recursion.
    return ins;
}
```

`friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, const DegreeAngle& angle);` should be

`friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, DegreeAngle& angle);` (as its definition).